# Como alterar o formato do resultado de uma query?

Tags: mysql, sql, linha-de-comando

Gostaria de saber se existe algum argumento no select que altere o formato do *result* para ser usado como *dump*. Exemplo:

```
create table `table_name` (`id` int, `value` text);
insert into `table_name` values (1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c");

select * from `table_name`;
/* Result: "insert into `table_name` values (1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")" */
```

Answer (score 1):

Paulo, nunca vi em nenhum banco de dados alguma função que faça o que você deseja, mas você pode obter o resultado similar montando o sql dentro do select usando a função concat(), com este seu exemplo ficaria desta forma:

```
select concat('insert into table_name values (',id,',',value,');') from table_name;
```

Cada linha do resultado será um insert com um registro da tabela.

Comment: Nunca vi também nada parecido pela cli (além do \G no mysql), porém devido ao fato de muitas ferramentas de banco de dados terem essa opção de exportar o resultado da query como insert, eu achei que talvez fosse possivel.
Creio que a abordagem mais apropriada seria realizando o `concat` como você comentou.

Answer (score 0):

Desconheço essa função de gerar o insert pelo SQL.

Contudo o MySql Workbench após execução do script tem a opção de export para vários formatos: CSV, HTML, JSON, **SQL INSERT** e etc.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção e resposta amigo, mas meu interesse seria realizar pela parte da cli mesmo :/